# Import swagger into existing project in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, maven, android-gradle-plugin, swagger

Hello I'd like to add swagger generated zip into my gradle powered android project in Android studio. Which way is the best practice to import it continuously every time when swagger file change?

Now I'm executing

```
mvn package
```

in unzipped dir from swagger UI generator, then I copy mvn-generated jar into libs in android project. I also copied dependencies from generated gradle file.

I'm sure somebody knows more elegant way how to deal with swagger in android studio.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options.  The easiest is to copy the files from your downloaded client into your project and add the dependencies from the `pom.xml` or gradle build file, both which are generated when using the `java` target in the online swagger codegen.

Answer (score 2):

My solution was to create a gradle module to download, unzip, and place the swagger files in my project.

I created an example on [github](https://github.com/PeeJWeeJ/AndroidStudioSwaggerUpdater):

All you should have to do is add the url for your swagger and possibly modify the path. I just posted it as an example and haven't tested if it will work in different applications, so I'm not 100% sure it's drag and drop.